# Execute Java script from objective c

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, adobe-edge

first of all , i know that there is a multiple question discuss this problem but honestly i cant get the correct use method ,  say i use adobe edge animate to create animated Html in out put i have edge action file contain this code

```
  (function($, Edge, compId){
var Composition = Edge.Composition, Symbol = Edge.Symbol; // aliases for commonly used Edge classes

   //Edge symbol: 'stage'
   (function(symbolName) {


   })("stage");

   //Edge symbol end:'stage'

   //=========================================================

   //Edge symbol: 'Slide_17'
   (function(symbolName) {   

   })("Slide_17");
   //Edge symbol end:'Slide_17'

   //=========================================================

   //Edge symbol: 'sections_bar_1'

   (function(symbolName) {   


  Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${Btn5}", "click", function(sym, e) {
     sym.getParentSymbol().stop("Se5");

     sym.$("icon1").show();
     sym.$("icon2").show();
     sym.$("icon3").show();
     sym.$("icon4").show();
     sym.$("icon5").hide();

     sym.$("Ellip").css({"top":"1419px","left":"1113px","-webkit-transition-duration":".5s"});

  });
  //Edge binding end

  Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${Btn4}", "click", function(sym, e) {
     sym.getParentSymbol().stop("Se4");

     sym.$("icon1").show();
     sym.$("icon2").show();
     sym.$("icon3").show();
     sym.$("icon4").hide();
     sym.$("icon5").show();

     sym.$("Ellip").css({"top":"1329px","left":"1076px","-webkit-transition-duration":".5s"});

  });
  //Edge binding end

  Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${Btn3}", "click", function(sym, e) {
     sym.getParentSymbol().stop("Se3");

     sym.$("icon1").show();
     sym.$("icon2").show();
     sym.$("icon3").hide();
     sym.$("icon4").show();
     sym.$("icon5").show();

     sym.$("Ellip").css({"top":"1296px","left":"996px","-webkit-transition-duration":".5s"});

  });
  //Edge binding end

  Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${Btn1}", "click", function(sym, e) {
     sym.getParentSymbol().stop("Se1");

     sym.$("icon1").hide();
     sym.$("icon2").show();
     sym.$("icon3").show();
     sym.$("icon4").show();
     sym.$("icon5").show();

     sym.$("Ellip").css({"top":"1429px","left":"879px","-webkit-transition-duration":".5s"});

  });
  //Edge binding end

  Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${Btn2}", "click", function(sym, e) {
     sym.getParentSymbol().stop("Se2");

     sym.$("icon1").show();
     sym.$("icon2").hide();
     sym.$("icon3").show();
     sym.$("icon4").show();
     sym.$("icon5").show();

     sym.$("Ellip").css({"top":"1333px","left":"912px","-webkit-transition-duration":".5s"});

  });
  //Edge binding end

  Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${close}", "click", function(sym, e) {
     sym.$("close").css({"top":"0px", "-webkit-transition-duration":".5s"});
     sym.$("rec").css({"-webkit-transform":"scaleX(0)", "-webkit-transition-duration":".5s"});
     sym.getParentSymbol().$("barBottom").css({"top":"1420px", "-webkit-transition-duration":".5s"});
     sym.getParentSymbol().$("sections_bar").css({"left":"-2048px", "-webkit-transition-duration":".5s"});
     //sym.getParentSymbol().getSymbol("sections_bar").deleteSymbol();


  });
  //Edge binding end



 })("sections_bar_1");
   //Edge symbol end:'sections_bar_1'

})(window.jQuery || AdobeEdge.$, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-41913470");
```

i use webViewJavaScriptBrige created by Marcus Westin

and use this code to call function from objective-c

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#Stage_Btn2').click()"];
```

but i cant get any action , so how can i call any function on this file